# How to properly dispose of refuse

Tags: dwarf-fortress

There are two kinds of refuse which I usually make into stockpiles: useful (like bones shells etc) and useless (corpses and body parts). The useless refuse causes problems for me. For one thing, you need to designate lots of space and it generates miasma. Also, the dwarves get horrified every time they go in because they see the dead goblins. Is there a way to dump this stuff down a pit? Do I even want to? I mean can't my butchers go in and grab a corpse to butcher it? Also, do I want to have a garbage dump? I never use that except quantum stockpiles (which I don't use anymore because it's cheating). So to recap: refuse pit? , butchering corpses in the stockpile? , how does garbage really work? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Evan! Just a gentle reminder to select a 'Best Answer' for your questions if you feel that someone has provided one, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There's all sorts of ways you can get rid of stuff in DF; for example, you can crush it into oblivion using a [bridge](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Bridge#Waste_disposal). Also, [this](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=81010.0) (slightly outdated) thread suggests that you shouldn't store corpses in refuse piles, as refuse is classified to be unbutcherable - note that not anything can be butchered (e.g. Goblins).

Garbage dumps can be useful in the right place; if a child snatcher decides to make an appearance in the middle of your full barracks, you're gonna want to remove the stinking corpse. Ideally you'll want to put your refuse pile outside, as corpses that are *not* subterranean do not produce [miasma](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Miasma).

Also, if you happen to be new to this wonderful game, I would highly suggest using http://dwarffortresswiki.org/ as it contains a wealth of information about several topics ranging from [basic](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Your_first_fortress) to very [complex](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Computing).

Comment: So bones and stuff should be stored in a stockpile near my butcher, there should be no corpse/body part pile, and I should have a garbage pit for miscellaneous stuff that I specifically designate to dump, right? Should I just do nothing with the corpses and body parts?

Comment: Also, where do "orders" come into play? Things like claiming body parts and outdoor refuse and whatnot

Comment: Also, corpses are a specific subsection of stockpile as well as a subsection of refuse stockpile.

Comment: I would clarify one statement here: dead things placed Outside do rot (to skeletons, and eventually to nothing), but don't produce miasma in the process.

Comment: @EvanAlder Orders, specifically for the collection of bodies, are useful when your fortress is under attack; you don't want civilian units running into the fray to pick up Urst McDead's corpse.

Also I'm not to keen on the difference between a refuse pile and a corpses stockpile, my guess is like you pointed out--a corpse stockpile will only contain corpses, a refuse will contain all sorts of stuff.

Also see http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Stockpile#Refuse for additional stockpile caviats

Comment: @PaulZ Whole skeletons (i.e. not partial or mangled) will not disappear, unfortunately. Some severed body parts will eventually rot into bones (or horn, tooth, hair, etc.) which can be used for other crafting purposes, depending on the animal they were taken from. (No dwarf-bone crafts for you!)